# Get object properties and values from array using lodash/underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dn4tn6xv/4/)

I have an array like this:

```
var array = [ { 
    'data-price': '0.00',
    'data-term': '532',
    'data-model_id': '409',
  },
  { 
    'data-price': '0.00',
    'data-term': '483',
    'data-model_id': '384',
  },
  { text: 'dffdfddgfdgf' } ];
```

I want to filter out the last object and extract `[{data-model_id:409},{data-model_id:384}]` from the first two objects. I have tried this code:

```
 var k = _(array).filter('data-model_id').pluck('data-model_id').value();
console.log(k);
```

and it returns an array of the values only, `["409", "384"]` . Is there a function to return the whole objects in lodash or underscore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using plain JS to show the logic: you need to `filter` out the elements that don't have the key, then `map` the new collection to another form:

```
array.filter( function(item){
    return 'data-model_id' in item;
  }).map( function( item ){
    return { 'data-model_id' : item['data-model_id'] }
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dn4tn6xv/7/

Answer (score 3):

What if I told you this is possible using just native javascript? Just use `Array.filter` and `Object.keys`, using the former to filter and the latter to get the keys and then returning a `Boolean` by comparing the index of the `Array` returned by `Object.keys`

```
var k = array.filter(function(obj){
   return Object.keys(obj).indexOf("data-model_id") > -1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In `lodash` you can do like this:

get full object

```
console.log(_.filter(array, 'data-model_id'));
```

get only `data-model_id` property

```
var res = _.chain(array).filter('data-model_id').map(function (el) {
  return _.pick(el, 'data-model_id');
}).value();
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/puloja/3/edit?js,console)